# Can i transfer money between two PayPal personal accounts?

Tags: paypal

I'm working on a shopping app. Merchants put their PayPal account on it  then people can pay direct to it. But I can't find any thing about it in [PayPal's Docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/). Is there a way can make it work?

Comment: Of course, or rather the owner of one of them can, but a merchant account is more likely to be a business account. Off topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed  to PayPal.

Comment: What i mean is paypal personal account, not  business account.